# UISplitViewController displayModeButtonItem not displaying

Tags: ios, splitview

I am not able to get iOS to display my button to show the `UISplitView` master view when in portrait mode (iPad) or landscape (iPhone 6+).

Right now I am using the following code, but it's not doing anything...

```
    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = displayModeButtonItem()
```

I tried putting that in the `viewDidLoad()` of my `UISplitView` subclass or in the `viewDidLoad()` of my detail main navigation controller.

It does not seem to do anything so far... Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was calling these methods on my `UINavigationController` instead of my `UIViewController`.

It is now working properly if I do so.

Comment: Made the same mistake today and spent a few hours trying to figure out what was going wrong. This answer still works today!

Comment: Could you show what you changed in code, or explain more in detail?  Also, in which class is `displayModeButtonItem()` defined?